# NuGet with TFS but without Package Restore

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to establish a private NuGet server for our team but I think I've found a show stopper.

If I have to download the solution from TFS the packages and its subdirectories are created but no actual files were downloaded. The result is that the dlls/assemblies are missing.

Is there a way to accomplish this without enabling package restore? I like to keep the corresponding dlls in the vcs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still no solution found. I think we really have to switch to the package restore feature.

Answer (score 0):

TFS by default ignores dll's when adding a folder to the pending changes (and doesn't work to well with binaries in general). Don't forget to add the dll's explicitly to your source control.

This is exactly why I prefer restoring the packages directly from a nuget feed when working with TFS :)

Comment: The dll's ARE part of the pending changes in case of the NuGet package. But they were not downloaded. Anyway: No way out?

Comment: So you installed packages from your private server into a solution, but they didn't contain anything? Then I'd check the packages and clear the local nuget cache on your development machine (found in %LOCALAPPDATA%\NuGet\Cache). If the packages are OK and they install correctly, all you have to do is checkin the entire Packages folder into VCS and that should do the trick.

Comment: Everything is fine with the packages and with the Check-in. Everything needed is included and could be compiled. But if another dev. wants to open/download the solution the "packages" folder and its subdirectories are created but without physical FILES in it (they ARE in TFS, but not downloaded!).

Comment: Only trying to help here, but it doesn't sound like a nuget problem, more like a TFS issue. If those files are in TFS, check if the developer doesn't have any unresolved merge conflicts. If he doesn't, then try to do an explicit get-latest version (and check the option to overwrite). Might be something corrupt in the local workspace.

Comment: Explicit get-latest with overwrite option works but only on the specific files that were missing. And that´s not acceptable. The problem is reproducable on different developer machines so it couldn´t be a corrupt workspace.